# System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException (signature algorithm) in Windows XP SP2 - visual studio 13 project

Tags: c#, deployment, migration, windows-xp, xml-signature

I'm working on a project which was built in visual studio 2008 and it was running fine in Windows XP, Windows 7, 8, and 10.

But then we migrated on visual studio 2013 [target framework-3.5, signature algorithm-sha256RSA are same as they were] and now I'm having this problem

It is working fine in windows 7, but when I tried to install it in windows XP-SP2 through "Click Once Application Deployment" I'm getting following exception.

> - Exception reading manifest from file:Desktop/MyApp-vs13/MyApp.application: the manifest may not be
>     valid or the file could not be opened.
>
>   - Source: System.Deployment
>   - Stack trace:          at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String
>       localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)          at
>       System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore
>       subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState&
>       subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options,
>       ServerInformation& serverInformation)             at
>       System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore
>       subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState&
>       subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
>         at
>       System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri
>       activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String
>       deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings,
>       String& errorPageUrl)             at
>       System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object
>       state)        --- Inner Exception ---
>       System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException
>       (SignatureValidation)
>   - Manifest XML signature is not valid.
>   - Source: System.Deployment
>   - Stack trace:          at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSignature(Stream
>       s)            at
>       System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String
>       localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)      --- Inner
>       Exception ---         System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
>   - SignatureDescription could not be created for the signature algorithm supplied.
>   - Source: System.Security
>   - Stack trace:          at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckSignedInfo(AsymmetricAlgorithm
>       key)          at
>       System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckSignature(AsymmetricAlgorithm
>       key)          at
>       System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckSignatureReturningKey(AsymmetricAlgorithm&
>       signingKey)           at
>       System.Deployment.Internal.CodeSigning.SignedCmiManifest.Verify(CmiManifestVerifyFlags
>       verifyFlags)          at
>       System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSignature(Stream
>       s)

Additional Information:

- Signature Algorithm : sha256RSA
- Project's Target framework : 3.5
- Project's Target platform : AnyCpu
- client OS : windows XP - Service Pack 2
- client .net framework : 3.5 (later I had installed 4.0, but result is
  same)

I know There are few questions similar to mine here, but common answer to all of them was "to remove signing" which is not option for me, Not even I can change "signature Algorithm"

All I have to successfully deploy and run my project in Windows XP SP2 with .net framework 3.5

Is there something I'm missing or some way to achieve it?

Comment: One more thing I would like to Add, when I uninstalled .NET framework 4.5 from my computer - windows 7, it is showing the same problem as windows XP, So it must be framework's problem. But with the same Signature algorithm it was working fine (Even in windows XP where 4.5 .NET framework is not even supported) when I was using visual studio 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP has been dead for years and it's last SP is SP3.

Don't attempt to do serious tasks on non supported environment as nobody guarantees.

Comment: I totally understand your point, even Microsoft corp. has limited their support. But many of my clients are still on windows XP - SP2, so I have no choice in this matter

Comment: @AmitNatural there are other approaches than ClickOnce which might not hit the same issue. You might check them out and switch to.